# keystroke in Guest os are not working properly in vbox

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I am using **VirtualBox-5.1** on Fedora 25. And every time i want to switch tabs in guest os , the vbox is switches with host. Simply any **alt+tab , ctrl+alt+down_arrow** not working inside Vbox guest os. What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

All key combinations containing **CTRL+ALT** work by replacing **CTRL+ALT** with **HOST**, **HOST** is the host key of VirtualBox and it is the right **CTRL** key by default (Your current one should be displayed at the bottom right of your VM window).
**ALT+TAB** works by simply pressing **ALT+TAB** while having the guest os window focused, if it doesn't work press **HOST** to change the focus for **ALT** key combinations to the guest and vice versa.

Comment: when i used **HOST** key with right_ctrl+alt+tab it shows two menu. **1.windows** **2.top bar** . But not switching inside VirtualBox

Comment: Why **right_ctrl+alt+tab**? **HOST** key should replace **CTRL+ALT**, so there can't be **ALT** inside your key combination and for using **ALT+other_key_except_CTRL** going in full screen should work but then no **HOST** key.

Comment: I done fullscreen in guest OS. Firefox was running on my host . Then i used **alt+tab** inside guest but the guest os pannel switched with firefox. this is happening. So tell me how to fix this

Comment: You can switch the focus for **ALT** key combinations between host and guest by pressing **HOST**, so simply press **HOST** once and then try **ALT+TAB**.

Comment: no. not working.

Comment: What exact version of VirtualBox are you using?(For example 5.1.24)

Comment: **VirtualBox-5.1-5.1.24_117012_fedora25-1**

Comment: Same with `6.0.14_Debian r132055`, on any VM guest. Hotkeys trigger the host. HOST key doesn't help, neither right_alt. Only workaround alt-startkey-tab, but that hurts...

Comment: Actually alt-tab can be changed via the OS settings, but there is no solution for the rest of the hotkeys combinations. Only workaround is to switch to XFCE or another desktop, since this is a gnome issue

Comment: @chefarov Are you using X11 or Wayland? Is ALT-TAB only caught by the host or also the guest? Have you focused the VM's window before using ALT-TAB and is the mouse cursor over the VM's window?

Comment: @testeaxeax Switching back to Xorg fixed the issue, it was a wayland bug, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know this is kinda old but it is still occurring, hopefully it will help others.

Maybe this problem is related to an upgrade of the system or some other similar system features change.


In overall, to restore these two (or other more) features, you may do it manually by:


**1.switch tabs (actually windows applications) in guest os:**

- go to **System Settings**.
- choose **Keyboard**.
- in **Shortcuts** tab, go to the **Navigation** choice, there, go down to **switch applications** and click on it then define your shortcut (in your case press **Alt+Tab**).

You can also configure other shortcuts such as **minimizing/maximizing the current window** by going (from the **3rd** point) into the **Windows** tab. Where you will find a set of features to configure.

Best regards,

Comment: You mean setting to `ALT+Q` or similar, since ALT+Tab will go to the host. Even so, however, the rest of the hotkeys, e.g start-key, alt+F_keys remain non functional (e.g going to host)

Comment: @chefarov well, I did not try it since long ago (sorry for the response delay) but I think that the switch-to-host will only occur if the guest window is selected but not while the focus is on the guest. With this said, ALT+Tab will still operate inside the guest (as long as the configuration that I mentioned are applied).